# Erro while binding data to grid by collection list

Tags: entity-framework-4, entity

I am trying to bind list collection to data-grid but its giving an error.

The type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.

Data Layer Code :

```
  public class Employees
 {
 public List<Employee> LoadEmployees()
     {
         try
         {
             EMployeeDB1Entities EE = new EMployeeDB1Entities();
             var Employees = EE.Employees.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("T"));
             return Employees.ToList();

            // var myCollection = new ObservableCollection<Employee>(this.LoadEmployees());

         }
         catch
         {
             return null;
         }
```

}

UI Layer Code

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Employees E1 = new Employees();

        // error gives in below line.
        dataGridView1.DataSource = E1.LoadEmployees();


    }
```

Whats the solution  ? 
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you referenced `System.Data.Entity` in your UI project?

Answer (score 1):

The error clearly states that you are missing the reference of System.Data.Entity class in your project, you need to add it by the same simple process. Right click on add reference , then .Net tab and select System.Data.Entity from the list.

and you will be good to go.